# Bokeh table with dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to draw a table using bokeh to represent a dictionary of dictionaries, but I can't figure out how to do it.
Here is my simple code:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn

def testTable():
    data = {'position1': {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0},
            'position2': {'x': 1.1, 'y': 2.3, 'z': 3},
            'position3': {'x': 2.9, 'y': 4.3, 'z': 3.1}}           

    source = ColumnDataSource(data)

    columns = [
            TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
            TableColumn(field="y", title="y"),
            TableColumn(field="z", title="z"),
        ]
    data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

    plot = column(widgetbox(data_table))

    show(plot)
```

When I run this code I get the error:

```
ValueError: expected an element of ColumnData(String, Seq(Any)), got {'position2': {'y': 2.3, 'x': 1.1, 'z': 3}, 'position3': {'y': 4.3, 'x': 2.9, 'z': 3.1}, 'position1': {'y': 0, 'x': 0, 'z': 0}}
```

What I would like to do is to create a table like this:

```
           x    y    z
position1  0    0    0
position2  1.1  2.3  3
position3  2.9  4.3  3.1
```

What is the right way to do it?

EDIT:

I was able to obtain something by refactoring the input data in a different way:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, column
from bokeh.io import output_file, show

def testTable():
    data = {'InitPosition': ['position1', 'position2', 'position3'],
            'x': [0,0,0],
            'y': [1.1, 2.3, 3],
            'z': [2.9, 4.3, 3.1]}           

    source = ColumnDataSource(data)

    columns = [
            TableColumn(field="InitPosition", title="Init Position"),
            TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
            TableColumn(field="y", title="y"),
            TableColumn(field="z", title="z")
        ]
    data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

    plot = column(widgetbox(data_table))

    show(plot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testTable()
```

However the drawn table looks like this:

[image: Bokeh table]

So the new question is: how to get rid of the first automatically drawn table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a boolean attribute `row_headers` that you can pass to the `DataTable` to enable/disable the row headers, i.e. the index column.

You could try something like:

```
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280, row_headers=False)
```